# python file manipulation

Tags: python, file

I have a directory /tmp/dir with two types of file names

> /tmp/dir/abc-something-server.log
>
> /tmp/dir/xyz-something-server.log
>
> ..
>
> ..

and

> /tmp/dir/something-client.log

I need append a few lines (these lines are constant) to files end with "client.log"

> line 1
>
> line 2
>
> line 3
>
> line 4

append these four lines to files end with "client.log"

Yes I found open () "a"  option will provide the desired result. but how to select the correct file that is, exclude server.log and choose client.log ?

and For files end with "server.log"

I needed to append after a keyword say "After-this".
"server.log " file has multiple entries of "After-this" I need to find the first entry of "After-this" and append above said four lines  keep the remaining file as it is.

Any help will be great appreciated :) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it "insert" in stead of append? Appending a file is possible, but inserting in the middle without some kind of (temporary) copying is not I believe. If the files are still opened by client or server strange things may happen while copying.

Comment: yes..for the server.log file it's insert in the middle .. not append.
no process is still using these files-so that's won't be problem.

Comment: Good question; clear about what you're after and why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not tested

```
import os,glob,fileinput
root="/tmp"
path=os.path.join(root,"dir")
alines=["line 1\n","line 2\n","line 3\n","line 4\n"]
os.chdir(path)
# for clients
for clientfile in glob.glob("*.client.log"):
    data=open(clientfile).readlines()
    data.append(alines)
    open("temp","w").write(''.join(data))
    os.rename("temp",clientfile)
for svrfile in glob.glob("*.server.log"):
    f=0
    for line in fileinput.FileInput(svrfile,inplace=1):
         ind=line.find("After-this")
         if ind!=-1 and not f:
             line=line[:ind+10] + ''.join(alines) + line[ind+10:]
             f=1
         print line
```

Comment: it says type error ...how to fix this ?
>open("temp","w").write(''.join(data))
>TypeError

and i think there is a typo --- 
is it 
>line=line[:ind+10] + ''.join(alist) + line[ind+10:]
or 
>line=line[:ind+10] + ''.join(alines) + line[ind+10:]

Comment: see edit. `data=data.append(alines)` should be just `data.append(alines)`. and yes, its a typo for the other one. You can just test it out right? run it with interpreter and find out.

Comment: I have changed the files as you said, i'm getting different error this time - 

File "file_mani.py", line 9, in <module>
    open("temp","w").write(''.join(data))
TypeError: sequence item 64: expected string, list found

Comment: do data+=alines instead of using append, append will append alines as a single element of type list.

Comment: Yes,,adding data+=alines does the trick. Thanks UncleZeiv.
Thanks for the script ,ghostdog74 !!!